# The code below sends a string and list through a client server network

Tags: python

My code isn't sending the list below to the server side. How do I  serialize list into bytes to be sent over a Clint server network?

Error message: info=pickle.loads(buf)
_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key,'H'.

```
import socket
import sys
from io import BytesIO 
import struct
import pickle
portnum = 5000
hostname = 'localhost'

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_addr = (hostname,portnum)
sock.connect(server_addr)
msg = "Hello There!"
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]

sock.send(str.encode(msg)) 
serial_grades = pickle.dumps(numbers)
sock.send(serial_grades)

print("Message sent")
sock.close()
print ("Sending message: ", msg)
print ("done.")
sock.close()

import struct
import socket
import sys
from io import BytesIO 
import pickle

port = 5000
hostname = 'localhost'

def byte_to_string(bytes_):
    bytes_ = str(bytes_)
    return bytes_[2:len(bytes_) - 1] 

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind((hostname, port))
sock.listen(2)
print ("Ready. Listening to socket...")

conn,addr = sock.accept()
buf = conn.recv(8092)
buf_2 = conn.recv(8092)

response = byte_to_string(buf)
info=pickle.loads(buf)

print(info)
print ("We've got a message "+str(response))
sock.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you one of the easiest way to send your list object via network. Let's define two functions. The first one is:

`def list_to_bytes(lst):
    return lst.__repr__().encode('utf-8')`

It takes the list instance and converts it to a bytes string. You should use it on the client side. And the second function is:

`def bytes_to_list(bts):
    return eval(bts.decode('utf-8'))`

The function above takes bytes string and converts it to the list instance by means of built-in `eval` function. Use described function on the server side.